# How does vscode remote connect to server when $HOME doesn't exist, and it can't be created?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

Here is the scenario:

- There's no home directory /home/<user_name> at server, and I don't have the permission to create it.
- When I connect to server remotely using vscode, it raises error msg:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/<user_name>: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/<user_name>’Creating the server install dir failed...
```

I configured ~/.ssh/config on windows side

```
Host <alias>
  HostName <user_name>
  User <user_name>
  RemoteCommand "export HOME=/another_directory"
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I connect to server using vscode in such condition?

[Remote - SSH Issue Link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8142)

Comment: I'd recommend you create an issue ticket to ask the maintainers of the "Remote - SSH" extension on [their github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release) (assuming that's the extension you're using). if you do, [edit] your post to add a link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

What it worked for me was to

1. remove the whole folder

> /home/<user_name>/.vscode-server

in other ssh ways, e.g., terminal on mac

2. reconnect using vscode ssh

I realized sometimes folder .vscode-server becomes /dev/null type, meaning the output to this folder will be automatically discarded. This creates the issue in vscode ssh.